# JobSchudaler update values

Tags: android

I have a JobSchudaler where it starts a notification function, I added a default value where its 90 min, also I allowed the user to choose his set Time period in minuets and store It inside the database table. However, because I wrote the JobSchualer in the main Activity once the app start and the Oncreate begin it will keep running with the default value for a long time, the Question is how do I get out of the onCreate default Value and force it to recheck the setPeriod
value.

Here is TaskSchudaler:

```
    protected void TaskSchudaler() {
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper (this);
    ProfileHelper profileHelper = databaseHelper.getTimeReminder ();
    GcmNetworkManager networkManger = GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(this);

    if(databaseHelper.checkReminderTable () == true){
        PeriodicTask taskOne = new PeriodicTask.Builder()
                .setService(JobSchualerHandler.class).setPeriod(5500).setFlex(20).setRequiresCharging(false).setTag("Task First").build();
        networkManger.schedule(taskOne);
        Log.w ("Empty", "its Says Empty");

    }else if (databaseHelper.checkReminderTable () == false){
        PeriodicTask taskOne = new PeriodicTask.Builder()
                .setService(JobSchualerHandler.class).setPeriod(profileHelper.TimePeriod*60).setFlex(20).setRequiresCharging(false).setTag("Task First").build();
        networkManger.schedule(taskOne);
        Log.w ("Not Empty", String.valueOf (profileHelper.TimePeriod*60));

    }
}
```

FYI.  the insertion of the SetPeriod happens within another fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cancel all the jobs associated with Periodic task and restart it with new time interval.
You can use [cancelAllTasks()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager.html#cancelAllTasks(java.lang.Class%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmTaskService%3E)) method to cancel all task associated with a service.

Other approach will be to use JobSchedule to perform you periodic task.
Job scheduler with same id will update the existing jobs with new value.

Comment: In the code above I tried to make sure it's the same Id. So I would think the only thing left is to cancel and restart the Periodic task, two issues here how can I do it exactly. And second how to recall it when the new vales inserted